# put and get request of one URL in angular that put doesn't work : Request method 'PUT' not supported"

Tags: angular, api, get, put

I have a Get and Put Request for API of the same URL Get works and returns the JSON but after that, I send the same JSON to put request and get this error: Request method 'PUT' not supported"

Here is the Code :

```
public getServiceTasks(serviceId: number, clearingCaseId: number, servicePartnerId: number): Observable<Array<ServiceWithTasks>> {
    const url = this.baseURL + Urls.CLEARING_CASE + clearingCaseId + Urls.SERVICE_TASKS;
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.set('serviceId', serviceId.toString());
    params = params.set('servicePartnerId', servicePartnerId.toString());
    return this.http.get<Array<ServiceWithTasks>>(url, { params: params });
}

public updateServiceTasks(serviceWithTasks: Array<ServiceWithTasks>, serviceId: number,
    clearingCaseId: number, servicePartnerId: number): Observable<string> {
    debugger
    const url = this.baseURL + Urls.CLEARING_CASE + clearingCaseId + Urls.SERVICE_TASKS;
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.set('serviceId', serviceId.toString());
    params = params.set('servicePartnerId', servicePartnerId.toString());
    const result = this.http.put<string>(url, serviceWithTasks, { params: params });
    return result;
}
```

First one works and returns the value , I even passed same JSON to PUT method and got error.

Comment: Have you tried something like Postman? I'm not sure the issue lies with the Angular code, but rather with the API

Comment: @shamPooSham yes I tried postman and same

Comment: Seems like PUT isn't implemented for that endpoint then. Who develops the API? If it's you, then you should make a question about how to implement the PUT endpoint. If it's someone else, talk to them

Comment: @ShamPooSham no its not me, so probably from the backend guys, ok tnx